# Mysql Create VIEW with CONCAT and two colums

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I'm trying to create a view with two extra fields. I have this code that does the job with one extra filed

```
CREATE VIEW STRANKEPView AS (
    SELECT *, COALESCE(CONCAT('P-',strp_ID)) AS strp_nas_br
    FROM STRANKEP 
);
```

I need to add one more filed as

```
CONCAT('A',strp_aa, '.')) AS strp_aa_nas_br
```

I can not find example of this anywhere and what ever i tried is not working. 
How can I join this? Something along lines:

```
CREATE VIEW STRANKEPView AS (
    SELECT *, COALESCE(CONCAT('P-',strp_ID)) AS strp_nas_br 
    AND COALESCE(CONCAT('A',strp_aa,'.')) AS strp_aa_nas_br
    FROM STRANKEP 
);
```

Or I need possibility to alter the VIEW that I created with first statement. But when i do this i get the error that STRANKEPView is not a table

```
ALTER VIEW STRANKEPView AS (
    SELECT *, COALESCE(CONCAT('A',strp_aa,'.')) AS strp_aa_nas_br
    FROM STRANKEPView 
);
```

Comment: Just replace the `AND` in your first attempt with a `,`

Comment: Why are you using `COALESCE` with only one argument?

Comment: A view can't select from itself, it would recurse infinitely.

Comment: @Nick Thank you very much, I tried a lot just not that...

Comment: @Barmar I construed this code from one example that included COALESCE whom find here on site and it was just working, so i left it as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change an existing view you use `ALTER VIEW`.

The fields you're selecting are separated with `,`, not `AND`.

```
ALTER VIEW STRANKEPView AS (
    SELECT *, CONCAT('P-',strp_ID) AS strp_nas_br,
              CONCAT('A',strp_aa,'.') AS strp_aa_nas_br
    FROM STRANKEP 
);
```

There's no point in using `COALESCE()` with just one argument, so I removed that from the view. The purpose of `COALESCE()` is to return an alternate value if the argument is `NULL`; it doesn't do anything useful if you don't supply the alternate value.